# C# How to "verify" that new connections are actually getting reused from connection pool

Tags: c#, database, connection, odbc, pooling

I have a simple c# code in which I am trying to open and close connections multiple times. How can I ensure that my new connections are coming from connection pool and that it is not hitting the database?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LBSService
{
    class MyClass    {
        public static OdbcConnection connection = null;       
        public void TestConnection()
        {
            string connectionstring = @"Dsn=my_database.IServer;Host=IServer;
                                        Database=my_database;Uid=informix;
                                        Pwd=Some@123";

            for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
            {
                string StrQuery = "select * from capture_files";
                connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionstring);
                connection.Open();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have limitation that I have to open an ODBC connection so answer related to ODBC is preferred.

Is there any data memeber within my 'connection' object or something where I can actually see how many unused connections are there in pool and how many are used by my application.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

> "How can I ensure that my new connections are coming from connection
>   pool and that it is not hitting the database"

That is slightly erroneous logic.  The connection pool is on the client side. Even if you reuse a connection from the pool, any command will still have to hit the database.

If you have ***exactly*** the same connection string (down to case even), then you will reuse a connection from the pool (provided it is turned on, which is the default).

The reason the connection pool exists is because setting up a connection requires some overhead.

[SQL Server Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx):

> Connecting to a database server typically consists of several
>   time-consuming steps. A physical channel such as a socket or a named
>   pipe must be established, the initial handshake with the server must
>   occur, the connection string information must be parsed, the
>   connection must be authenticated by the server, checks must be run for
>   enlisting in the current transaction, and so on.
>
> In practice, most applications use only one or a few different
>   configurations for connections. This means that during application
>   execution, many identical connections will be repeatedly opened and
>   closed. To minimize the cost of opening connections, ADO.NET uses an
>   optimization technique called connection pooling.
>
> Connection pooling reduces the number of times that new connections
>   must be opened. The pooler maintains ownership of the physical
>   connection. It manages connections by keeping alive a set of active
>   connections for each given connection configuration. Whenever a user
>   calls Open on a connection, the pooler looks for an available
>   connection in the pool. If a pooled connection is available, it
>   returns it to the caller instead of opening a new connection. When the
>   application calls Close on the connection, the pooler returns it to
>   the pooled set of active connections instead of closing it. Once the
>   connection is returned to the pool, it is ready to be reused on the
>   next Open call.
>
> Only connections with the same configuration can be pooled. ADO.NET
>   keeps several pools at the same time, one for each configuration.
>   Connections are separated into pools by connection string, and by
>   Windows identity when integrated security is used. Connections are
>   also pooled based on whether they are enlisted in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the ADO.net [Performancecounters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  to ensure that there is only once active Database Connection

Answer (score 0):

You may use timings in your function with adding and removing to the connection string this:

```
Pooling=false;
```

If timings vary - then without this string connections are reused

Like this:

```
public long TestConnection(bool usepooling)
{
  string connectionstring = @"Dsn=my_database.IServer;Host=IServer;
                                    Database=my_database;Uid=informix;
                                    Pwd=Some@123;Pooling="+usepooling.ToString;


  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
  for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
  {
    string StrQuery = "select * from capture_files";
    connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionstring);
    sw.Start();
    connection.Open();
    connection.Close();
    sw.Stop();
  }

  return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

}
```